# DAX Counting Groups of Repetition in Row

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

Not long into my DAX understanding and i've hit a brickwall.

I need to create a measure that counts if a RANDOM_PERSON_ID is repeated 5 times.

So, my measure value with the test dataset should be 1 (9662AF155704B3F7).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Danny

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Amitchandac @ community.powerbi.com for giving me the answer.

```
    COUNTAX (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Table,
                Table[RANDOM_PERSON_ID],
                "EqualTo5", COUNTA ( Table[RANDOM_PERSON_ID] )
            ),
            [EqualTo5] = 5
        ),
        Table[RANDOM_PERSON_ID]
    )
```